# Are these two Linq queries functionally equivalent in Linq-to-Entities?

Tags: linq-to-entities

```
//Limit records, order remaining records, then take first or default.
x.Where(predicateExpression)
.OrderBy(rankExpression)
.FirstOrDefault();

//Order records, take first of ordered set that matches predicate.
x.OrderBy(rankExpression)
.FirstOrDefault(predicateExpression)
```

I'm curious whether the above Linq queries are equivalent when translated to SQL in Linq-to-Entities.  I'm fairly certain they're equivalent when running against in-memory sets, because FirstOrDefault would iterate over the ordered set in order while skipping records that don't match the predicate, which would be equivalent to filtering them out before ordering.  However, in Linq-To-Entities, this would be translated to SQL, so I'm concerned that applying the predicate (i.e. a 'where' clause) after ordering would result in an intermediate unordered set which first or default would operate on.  Perhaps one of these is not even valid in Linq-to-Entities at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Those two Linq queries generate an identical SQL query of the following form according to SQL Server Profiler:

```
--pseudo-SQL
SELECT TOP (1) <<columns from Extent1>>
FROM <<tableName>> AS [Extent1]
WHERE <<predicateExpression>>
ORDER BY <<rankExpression>> ASC
```